# How to add helper specific scripts into the view in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

The problem I have faced is I want to create an HTML helper method to create a specific element which uses some JavaScript code to work fine. But, I want to add script tag automatically to the HTML, if the helper is used in the view.

If the helper is called more than once in the view, it is undesirable to add more than one script tag.

Now, Is it possible and if so How can I do that?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, Currently I placed the script tag along with the element itself.